# Rolling "McGyver" in Savage Worlds

Tags: savage-worlds

For the first time in many Savage Worlds campaigns over several years, a player has the "McGyver" Edge.

The first benefit of the Edge is clear cut: when rolling Repair on the "hyperspace torque converter", the PC suffers no penalty for improvising tools and fixes.

The second benefit is the ability to build one-shot widgets, gizmos, and whatchamacallits to suit the need of the moment.  Some of these "moments" can be literally life-saving, so the McGyver gizmo can be very significant to the plot/play.

Such a significant act should require a dice roll, but against what trait?  Repair?  Smarts? Something else?

Nowhere in the book can we find a hint. Searching and wading through endless threads at the company's forum brings no joy.  I'm hoping the good folk at StackExchange can provide a crisp and clear answer.

We don't care which edition of "Savage Worlds" rules may reveal the secret. If it is a newer version than we're using, the answer is still likely to be useable, or at least provide guidance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Repair

Per the McGyver Edge in the current Adventure Edition (page 49):

> Given a few simple items, he can **make a
> Repair roll** to craft improvised weapons,
> explosives, or tools, that last until used or the
> end of the encounter (GM’s call). This takes
> one entire turn, and he can’t move or take any
> other actions while constructing the device.

Emphasis added.

The rest of the Edge provides guidance on the statistics the improvised weapons and explosives might have.

Comment: Cheers!  I guess we'll have to hunting for the Adventure Edition!